# When listing the contents of /usr/sbin what is the meaning behind color codes of individual programs?

Tags: macos, bash

I see dozens of programs, some written in different colors in my shell, others with different background colors.  Google isn't helping on this.

[image: sbin screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a product of using `ls --color` (you probably have an alias for this; type `alias` with no args to see what your current `ls` alias(es) is/are).

Use `dircolors` or `echo $LS_COLORS` to see system-specific meanings.

Here are some examples I copied and pasted from a post on the [askubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/a/61345)

```
NORMAL 00 # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE 00 # normal file
DIR 01;34 # directory
LINK 01;36 # symbolic link. (If you set this to 'target' instead of a
 # numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.)
FIFO 40;33 # pipe
SOCK 01;35 # socket
DOOR 01;35 # door
BLK 40;33;01 # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01 # character device driver
ORPHAN 40;31;01 # symlink to nonexistent file, or non-stat'able file
SETUID 37;41 # file that is setuid (u+s)
SETGID 30;43 # file that is setgid (g+s)
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 37;44 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
# archives or compressed (bright red)
# archives or compressed (bright red)
.tar 01;31
.tgz 01;31
# image formats
.jpg 01;35
.jpeg 01;35
.gif 01;35
.bmp 01;35
# audio formats
.aac 00;36
.flac 00;36
.ogg 00;36
```

Comment: @BryceJohnson Cool; if you think it's a good answer, feel free to hit the checkbox ;)

Comment: was just waiting on the minimum time to pass. But thanks, it's a perfect answer.